# Editing large posts on android tablet doesn't allow full scroll down

Tags: bug, status-norepro, editing, user-interface

I tried to edit a larger post with my tablet. After scrolling down some lines it stopped and didn't get show the last ones. 
It also doesn't show the usual scroll down handle.

I'm using a catnova tablet with an android os, the built-in browser, and the SwiftKey keyboard.

Thanks,

**EDIT from my PC**

Indicated in red, the missing handle on my tablet:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you sure it's missing, and not just off the right edge of the screen?

Comment: @Hurkyl I added a shot from the tablet...

Comment: As a temporary workaround, I've had success in similar situations by using highlighting to force a region to scroll. That is, click and drag to start highlighting text, and drag past the boundary of the region. This will often cause the region to scroll. Of course, arrow keys or ctrl-home/ctrl-end should do that too.

Comment: @Hurkyl Ok I'll try. My current work around is writing short posts... ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Touch devices usually don't show scrollbars for such things. There's nothing we can do about that.

That said, I can't reproduce your issue -- editing exactly the same answer on my tablet (Acer Iconia A500, running ICS) allowed me to scroll through the full content of the editor area. [Here's a (shaky and flickering) video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eQlE1Ayx6cY) of me doing just that.

Comment: Thanks, +1 for the video. The thing is (and maybe now it became obvious that it's a problem of my tablet) that I can't scroll down to the very end. It stops at the last line of the comment area. Why not putting your video at a ["HowTo"](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/howto) page? ;-)